# Is the GCP Folder resource alpha?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Its not clear to me if the GCP Folder resource is alpha or publicly available ? The API around it `gcloud alpha resource-manager folders`  certainly seems alpha . Can I go ahead and solution the structure using folders or not yet  ?

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be a definitive answer (occasionally documentation may be lagging behind), one way to check if a particular [`gcloud` command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/) (use the left side bar for navigation) is alpha, beta or generally available is to check for a **Notes** section at the bottom of the respective command's documentation page.

In particular for [`gcloud alpha resource-manager folders`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/resource-manager/folders/) you see:

> **NOTES**
>
> This command is currently in ALPHA and may change without notice.

By comparison, the [`gcloud alpha app update`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/app/update) command shows:

> NOTES
>
> This command is currently in ALPHA and may change without notice.
>   These variants are also available:
>
> - $ [gcloud app update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/update)
> - $ [gcloud beta app update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/update)

Since `gclod app update` is available it means the feature is generally available, thus covered by SLA, so it's safe to base solutions on it.

But `gcloud alpha resource-manager folders` doesn't show a `gcloud beta resource-manager folders` or a `gcloud resource-manager folders`, so it's indeed only an alpha release.

Neither alpha nor beta features are covered by SLAs and may change at any time. That's not to say you can't start working on a solution using them, as long as you're prepared to revise it or switch to some other solution if/when things change (and, of course, you don't expect a service SLA for them). It's really up to you.

As for the Cloud Folders feature itself, it reached General Availability. From [the July 24, 2017 release note](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/release-notes#july_24_2017):

> Folders General Availability
>
> Cloud [folders](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders) are nodes in the Cloud Platform Resource Hierarchy.
>   A folder can contain projects, other folders, or a combination of
>   both. You can use folders to group projects under an organization in a
>   hierarchy. For example, you organization might contain multiple
>   departments, each with its own set of Cloud Platform resources.
>   Folders allows you to group these resources on a per-department basis.
>   Folders are used to group resources that share common IAM policies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question was more about specifically , the Folder resource type being generally available or not and not the API .